# Reload table inside div, columns get squashed

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with several tables inside a panel body. One of those tables, inside a row div and the panel div, I wanted to reload after the user spawns and then dismisses a modal. My code works, but when the table is reloaded [it gets squashed like so](http://abload.de/img/tableh0k1j.png).

Is it not possible to reload a table within a panel body?

EDIT: the table is first included at the bottom like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Sales by Month -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="text-center">Sales By Month</h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead><th></th><th><?=$last_year;?></th><th><?=$this_year;?></th></thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++):
                    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m',$i);
                    $t = $this_array[$i]?? 0;
                    $l = $last_array[$i]?? 0;
                    $this_total += $t;
                    $last_total += $l;
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$dt->format("F");?></td>
                    <td><?=money($l);?></td>
                    <td><?=money($t);?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endfor ;?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold" class="text-center">Year Total:</strong><td><?=money($last_total);?></td><td><?=money($this_total);?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Low Inventory -->
<?php include 'low_inventory.php'; ?>

</div>
</div>  <<<<<< this div closes the whole panel
```

the page itself looks like this:

```
<div id="low-inventory" class="col-md-8">
<?php
  require_once 'core/init.php';
  $low_inventory = $db->query("SELECT a.stock, a.id AS 'stock_id', a.product_id, a.threshold, b.title, c.size FROM stock a JOIN products b ON a.product_id = b.id
                                                          JOIN sizes c ON a.size = c.id WHERE (stock < 5 AND threshold = 0) OR (stock < threshold AND threshold > 0) ORDER BY stock ASC");
?>

  <h3 class="text-center">Low Inventory</h3>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-hand-pointer">
    <thead class="noninteractive"><th>Product</th><th>Size</th><th>Stock</th><th>Stock ID</th><th>Threshold</th></thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php while($low = mysqli_fetch_assoc($low_inventory)): ?>
        <tr <?=empty($low['stock'])? 'class="danger" ':'';?> onclick=show_stock(<?=$low['product_id'];?>)>
          <td><?=$low['title'];?></td>
          <td><?=$low['size'];?></td>
          <td><?=$low['stock'];?></td>
          <td><?=$low['stock_id'];?></td>
          <td><?=$low['threshold'];?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile ;?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And is reloaded by this:

```
$("#low-inventory").load("<?=ADMINURL;?>low_inventory.php");
```

Comment: @Gene R yep, see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `<div id="low-inventory" class="col-md-8">` outside `low_inventory.php`:

```
<div id="low-inventory" class="col-md-8">
    <?php include 'low_inventory.php'; ?>
</div>
```

otherwise after reload you get double wrapped:

```
<div id="low-inventory" class="col-md-8">
    <div id="low-inventory" class="col-md-8">
        ...
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.